# Is there a Pure Java NSSearchField replacement?

Tags: java, swing, search, user-interface

As the title says, has anyone (preferably a well established library) got a better version of what this chap tried to accomplish in 2004?

http://elliotth.blogspot.co.uk/2004/09/cocoa-like-search-field-for-java.html

There are a load of questions on stackoverflow about getting rounded borders, setting the icon, etc. But none of them seem to really hit the nail on the head with regards to getting something that actually looks, feels and behaves like a proper search bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JXSearchField from SwingX is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: I've looked at it - it looks horrible and has lots of additional parameters which make it bloated and ill-suited to purpose.

Comment: If it does too much for your needs you can copy the code and remove the extra features.

Comment: Emmanual: I was using the JXSearchPanel. You suggestion is indeed exactly what I am after. I didn't see it because: a) all the links to the SwingX docs are currently out of action b) the Webstart doesn't work c) Netbeans doesn't import this as a "marked bean" in the visual UI editor. As a bonus, I can now see a *load* of other SwingX widgets that I didn't know about until now.

Comment: Glad to help :) The SwingX documentation is seriously broken nowadays, but the quality and usefulness of the code is really great.